# Android/iOS: Show a list sorted by actual distance

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, location

On a mobile app I would like to show a list view where restaurants are shown sorted by ACTUAL driving distance from the users location (NOT straight line path). The users GPS coordinates are sent to the API.

Is there a way with which we can show the list sorted by actual driving distance without too much processing. Since its actual distance I assume we have to use something like google maps API

Anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use google map API to calculate the distance between 2 points, or even its expected driving duration.

> The Google Maps Distance Matrix API returns information based on the
>   recommended route between start and end points, as calculated by the
>   Google Maps API, and **consists of rows containing duration and distance
>   values for each pair.**
>
> This service does not return detailed route information. Route
>   information can be obtained by passing the desired single origin and
>   destination to the Google Maps Directions API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Some example of the row value:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "duration": {
  "value": 340110,
  "text": "3 jours 22 heures"
   },
   "distance": {
      "value": 1734542,
      "text": "1 735 km"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So if there are 25 restaurants can I pass one origin and 25 destinations using this API? Have you used it? Is it fast enough to get this information in real time. I only need the distance and not the route.

Comment: @Prasanth yes you can do 1 origin and 25 destinations. I use it and the response it very quick. It only gives the distance values but not the directions. There is a directions API if you would like to get route information as well.